# Why is Conda so much slower with yml file?

Tags: python, conda

I am trying to re-create an environment across different OS. Using `conda env export --from-history`, I created the following yml file:

```
name: mlflow_env
channels:
  - conda-forge
dependencies:
  - numpy
  - lightgbm
  - squarify
  - holidays
  - lunardate
  - lunarcalendar
  - sqlalchemy
  - pandas
  - geopy
  - pgeocode
  - psycopg2
  - cython
  - scikit-learn
  - mlflow
  - pyarrow
```

Once I run `conda env create --file conda_lt.yml python=3.9` on any of my two systems, it takes hours to solve the environment, which it eventually solves.

*However* if I try to run `conda create -c conda-forge -n mlflow_env numpy lightgbm squarify holidays lunardate lunarcalendar sqlalchemy pandas geopy pgeocode psycopg2 cython scikit-learn mlflow pyarrow`, solving the environment takes less than 30 seconds.

In my understanding the two commands should really result in the same environment, so I am wondering what is the difference and why the `yml` installation is so much slower. Naturally, any suggestion to make the `yml` installation as quick as the other is welcomed.

Comment: The `python=3.9` should be specified *in the YAML*. Not locking down a Python version (through minor) can be a major solving challenge. BTW, consider switching to [Mamba](https://mamba.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (`conda install -n base -c conda-forge mamba`)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
conda update conda
conda update conda-build
conda install -n base conda-libmamba-solver
conda config --set solver libmamba
```

My answer is based on the issue raised [in Conda's issue tracker](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/11919).